Pygments newlines and white-space causing lexing errors
( This question needs to be reworked as all the problems except those involving conditional instructions have been solved. As the question is now, it's a mess )
First, a big N.B. : I am not a Python programmer -- I just know enough from reading the Pygments documentation and browsing the source of Pygments' available lexers on Github to know how to write a Pygments lexer.

I have been working on a Jazz / SASM Saturn assembly syntax highlighter in Pygments. When I first began this endeavor, I thought the task would be extremely easy, but I soon ran into problems involving either quirks in how Pygments processes newlines and white-space, of which I don not understand the details and I have been pulling my hair out trying to get the lexer to work to no avail, hence my post here.
Jazz / SASM syntax has some white-space sensitive requirements, particularly that a label has to start in column one or two -- I don't know if this is part of the problem.
The first problem is that when a label starts in column two and is preceded by a blank line ( ie. just '\n' ) the label is marked as a lexing error or the whole line is marked as lexing error if a comment follows the label on the same line. EDIT It seems that something ( ie. any valid Jazz / SASM assembly code or comments etc. ) has to precede the blank line in order to replicate this problem.
INPUT :
* Replace this with any valid Jazz / SASM comments or code

 =lbl1 * This is a comment

OUTPUT :

The second problem is quite strange and I have no idea what's causing it : If a full-line comment ( which must start in column one with an asterisk ) is preceded by a blank line, then if there's an instruction in the text that one would think would be commented out, instead it generates a lexing error for said instruction text. EDIT I can't seem to replicate this exact problem (perhaps there is something wrong with the lexing tuple for the instruction class I used, or the instruction was malformed?), but what I have noticed is that what should be a comment is processed as an instruction. In addition, as with problem one, something has to precede the blank line to produce the problem.
INPUT :
* Replace this with any valid Jazz / SASM comments or code

* B=0 S

OUTPUT :

For the third problem further explanation of Jazz / SASM syntax is needed : All conditional instructions must be followed by a 'GOYES label' or just a 'RTNYES' on the next line. The first sub-issue I'm encountering here is that if the conditional instruction has trailing spaces, which should be handled by the comment processing code, then Pygments marks said white-space as a lexing error.
INPUT :
* Replace this with any valid Jazz / SASM comments or code

  ?A=B W    
  GOYES lbl1

OUTPUT :

Additionally, the conditional instructions seem to be immune to whatever is causing the lexing errors associated with problem one ie. if the conditional instruction is preceded by a label on the same line, irrespective if it starts in column one or two and it's preceded by a blank line, then Pygments seems to process the whole line without lexing errors.
INPUT :
* Replace this with any valid Jazz / SASM comments or code

  ?A=B W
  GOYES lbl1


OUTPUT :

Lastly, the required 'GOYES label' or 'RTNYES' on the next line after the conditional is always marked as a lexing error by Pygments.
INPUT :
* Replace this with any valid Jazz / SASM comments or code

  ?D=C W
  GOYES lbl1
  
  ?B=A P
  RTNYES

OUTPUT :

Now, I know all the above might not make a lot of sense because it is divorced from the source code, so, WLOG, I've included the Pygments lexer code which just processes two instruction classes, white-space, labels and comments. The instruction classes are : setting a register to zero and conditional instructions that perform an equality comparison of two registers.
( Note that the following source snippet has been updated so that the problems described above, except for problems involving the conditional instructions, have been eliminated )
from pygments.lexer import RegexLexer, bygroups
from pygments.token import *
import logging

class SasmJazzLexer(RegexLexer):
    name = 'SASM'
    aliases = ['SASM', 'Sasm', 'sasm', 'JAZZ', 'Jazz', 'jazz']
    filenames = ['*.A', '*.a']
    
    # Register fields
    fields = r'(P|WP|XS|X|S|M|B|A|W)'
    
    # Regex for label or symbol    
    symbol = r'((?:[:=][(=:#0-9][^,\s)]{,11})|(?:[:=]?[^(=:#0-9*,\s)\n][^,\s]{,11}))'
    
    
    tokens = {
        'root': [
            # Whitespace
            (r'^\s+$', Whitespace),

            # Single line comment starting with '*' in column one
            (r'^\*.*$', Comment.Single),
            
            # Whitespace or instructions
            (r'^( {2,})|(\t)\s*', Whitespace, 'possible_instructions'),
            
            # Label starting on column one or two and followed by a comment            
            (r'(^ ?)' + symbol + r'(\s+)(\*.*$)', bygroups(Whitespace, Name.Label, Whitespace, Comment.Single)),
            
            # Label starting in column one or two and followed by whitespace or instructions
            (r'(^ ?)' + symbol + r'(\s+)', bygroups(Whitespace, Name.Label, Whitespace), 'possible_instructions'),
        ],
        'possible_instructions': [
            # Just whitespace or empty line -- emit token and bail
            (r'\s+$', Whitespace, '#pop'),
            
            #
            # Register tests
            #
                        
            (r'(\?)([A-C])(=)([A-C])(\s+)' + fields, bygroups(Punctuation, Name.Builtin, Operator, Name.Builtin, Whitespace, Name.Builtin), ('possible_comment_cond', 'conditionals')),
            (r'(\?)([CD])(=)([CD])(\s+)' + fields, bygroups(Punctuation, Name.Builtin, Operator, Name.Builtin, Whitespace, Name.Builtin), ('possible_comment_cond', 'conditionals')),
            (r'(\?)(([A-D])(=)(\3))(\s+)' + fields, bygroups(Punctuation, Error, Name.Builtin, Operator, Name.Builtin, Whitespace, Name.Builtin), ('possible_comment_cond', 'conditionals')),
            
            #
            # Arithmetic instructions
            #
            
            # r=0 fs
            # possibly followed by a comment
            (r'([A-D])(=)(0)(\s+)' + fields, bygroups(Name.Builtin, Operator, Name.Builtin, Whitespace, Name.Builtin), 'possible_comment'),
        ],
        'possible_comment': [
            #
            # Comment processing code
            #
            
            # Just whitespace or empty line -- emit token and bail
            (r'\s*$', Whitespace, '#pop:2'),
            
            # Trailing comment
            (r'\s+\S.*$', Comment.Single, '#pop:2')
        ],
        'possible_comment_cond': [
            #
            # Comment processing code for conditionals
            #
            
            # Just whitespace or empty line -- emit token and bail
            (r'\s*$', Whitespace, '#pop'),
            
            # Trailing comment
            (r'\s+\S.*$', Comment.Single, '#pop')
        ],
        'conditionals': [
            #
            # GOYES and RTNYES processing code
            #

            (r'(^ {2,})(GOYES)(\s+)' + symbol, bygroups(Whitespace, Keyword, Whitespace, Name.Label), 'possible_comment'),
            (r'(^ {2,})(RTNYES)', bygroups(Whitespace, Keyword), 'possible_comment'),
        ]
    }

In the above, if a line is not a full-line comment, then it either matches a label in column one or two which is possibly followed by an instruction ( in state 'possible_instructions' ) after which may follow an comment ( handled by the state 'possible_comment' which in this case there is no need to use an asterisk ) separated by the instruction by white-space.
For the conditional instructions, two states are pushed to the stack :
('possible_comment_cond', 'conditionals')

The 'possible_comment_cond' state is needed because every tuple in the 'possible_comment' state pops two stack levels which would pop the 'conditionals' state which is needed to process the 'GOYES label' or 'RTNYES' that must follow a conditional instruction.
Note that I have been generating a complete HTML document to test my lexer using
python3 -m pygments -f html -O full -o test.html -x -l pygments_sasm_lexer_5.py:SasmJazzLexer test.txt


Hopefully I've included enough information for this question to be understood -- if I haven't, please comment and I'll add more details if necessary.
Also, I apologize for the ugly screencaps of the rendered output HTML, but I can't paste in all five of the HTML outputs without exceeding the Stackoverflow character limit.

Well, I replaced the 'symbol' variable with a regular expression that should have solved at least some of the above problems, especially the problem with a single line comment ( asterisk in column one ) sometimes being interpreted as an instruction, but I've seen no change in the output.
symbol = r'((?:[:=][(=:#0-9][^, )]{,11})|(?:[:=]?[^(=:#0-9*, ][^, )]{,11}))'

To break down the above regex, it's supposed to match anything up to twelve characters long, except a comma, space or right parentheses, and that starts with a "special character" ( '(', '=', ':', '#', and '0' through '9') if and only if the symbol is prefixed with a '=' or a ':' . If the symbol does not start with a special character and also does not start with an asterisk, then it matches anything ( again, except a comma, a space, or a right parentheses ), again, up to twelve characters long, and optionally prefixed by a ':' or a '=' .
As far as I can see, the regex I've supplied does as I've explained above.
In addition, white-space processing was a little bugged in that said white-space was being passed in regex capturing groups to the 'bygroups' callback -- now it's processed separately and given the token type 'Whitespace' . This, though, produces no change in the output.
I'm at a lost as to what's generating the lexing errors listed in this question.

I went ahead and registered / installed my custom lexer with Pygments on a system-wide level and ran the lexer debugger on it with test input and it appears than the problem is caused by newlines.
Specifically, I think I've found the problem, or at least part of the problem : The regexes in my code mishandle newlines, or, more precisely, don't handle them at all -- it completely slipped my mind - oops.
When I have the time, if I can resolve the problems caused by this then I'll answer my own question.

Well, I mistakenly thought, from the lexer debugger output, that part of the problem was being caused by blank lines consisting just of a newline, but, it seems that Pygments just eats blank lines by default.
The problems I presented here, except for the problems with the conditional instructions, appear to have been caused by a missing tuple that handles lines consisting entirely of white space and also a stupid bug in the symbol regex. Regarding the regex, I had accidentally complemented a bracketed character class that included a space when I actually needed the escaped character class '\s' instead of a space.
The correct regex follows :
r'((?:[:=][(=:#0-9][^,\s)]{,11})|(?:[:=]?[^(=:#0-9*,\s)\n][^,\s]{,11}))'

( It's also been corrected in the source snippet, along with removing a bunch of superfluous EOL '$'s from that regexes that process white-space )
As for the problems with the conditional instructions, the "GOYES label" or "RTNYES" are still marked as a lexing error ( as well as any comments on the same line and after the test instruction ). As to why, I have no idea.

Well, I see an error in the symbol / label regex that is most likely causing at least problem two : the regex allows the single line comment delimiter to be the first character of a symbol — I can’t believe I didn’t notice this until now.
